# Accessing distribution URL directly gives XML error

Tags: wordpress, cdn, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently setting up the Amazon Cloudfront distribution and S3 bucket for my Wordpress website. I set up new S3 bucket for the site and i'm using the S3 offload plugin for wordpress to store any images in this bucket.

I set up the cloudfront distribution to point to this bucket. Everything seems to be workings and when I inspect the image in the media manager, it does point to the bucket URL and load from this bucket.

But when I access the cloudfront distribution URL directly, 
( xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net ), I am getting a page with the following message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
   <HostId>
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

The xxxxx are just some random encrypted numbers and letters.

If I access the cloudfront distribution URL directly ( xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net ), shouldn't this be mirroring my actual website?

Or do I need to set up 2 cloudfront distributions for the same domain?

One that is pulling media from my S3 bucket and then a second distribution that is mirroring the actual website??